# Parse a line of text with template parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have some files with some space-separated data. I want a function `parse` that accepts just a filename and a function that acts on all of the elements on a single line. So for instance, if I have a file that has data in the format

```
int float string
int float string
int float string
...
```

then I want to have a function `parse` that accepts the filename containing this data, as well as a lambda that will process each line. If I knew how many elements were on each line (in this case 3), then I could do this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename Func, typename A, typename B, typename C>
void parse(const string & filename, Func func){

    string line;
    // TODO: Get line from file, not cin
    // std::ifstream file(filename);
    while (std::getline(cin, line)) {

        stringstream ss(line);
        A a;
        B b;
        C c;
        ss >> a >> b >> c;
        func( a, b, c );
    }

}

int main()
{
    auto forEach = [](int a, float b, string c){ cout << a << "," << b << "," << c << endl; }; 
    parse<decltype(forEach),int,float,string>( "test.txt", forEach );
    return 0;
}
```

The above code is agnostic to the types of the arguments, but requires exactly 3 values on each line. I would like help in extending this to a version where the number of arguments per line is either

1. inferred from the `Func` type (this would be the ideal scenario).
2. specified as a template parameter pack.

For example, I would image case 1 looking like

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename Func>
void parse(const string & filename, Func func){

    string line;
    // TODO: Get line from file, not cin
    // std::ifstream file(filename);
    while (std::getline(cin, line)) {

        stringstream ss(line);
        // TODO Infer from the type Func that it requires 
        // int, float, string 
        // Then use a stringstream to parse those values from `line`
        // and pass the results to func  
        func( ... );
    }

}

int main()
{
    auto forEach = [](int a, float b, string c){ cout << a << "," << b << "," << c << endl; }; 
    parse<decltype(forEach)>( "test.txt", forEach );
    return 0;
}
```

If that isn't possible, then I would accept a solution using a parameter pack. I just don't get how to do that. I imagine that the solution would look like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename Func, typename ...Args>
void parse(const string & filename, Func func){

    string line;
    // TODO: Get line from file, not cin
    // std::ifstream file(filename);
    while (std::getline(cin, line)) {

        stringstream ss(line);
        // TODO: Use Args to extract parse the appropriate number of 
        // parameters from `line` and pass the result to `func`
        func( ... );
    }

}

int main()
{
    auto forEach = [](int a, float b, string c){ cout << a << "," << b << "," << c << endl; }; 
    parse<decltype(forEach),int,float,string>( "test.txt", forEach );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is usually done using recursion, where each recursive call reads *one* value.

Comment: Also note that "string" is really a broad term, the last data should be read using `std::getline` if you want to handle a string containing spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

function traits can be found with `operator()` (with no overloads) or function pointer

```
template<typename C> struct function_trait : function_trait<decltype(&C::operator())> {};

template <typename C, typename Ret, typename...Args>
struct function_trait<Ret (C::*)(Args...) const> : function_trait<Ret(Args...)> {};
// Handle volatile, reference on this, C-ellipsis combination... 
template <typename Ret, typename...Args>
struct function_trait<Ret (*)(Args...)> : function_trait<Ret(Args...)> {};

template <typename Ret, typename...Args>
struct function_trait<Ret (Args...)>
{
    using args = std::tuple<Args...>;
};
```

Then

```
template <typename Func, typename Tuple>
void parse(std::istream& is, Func func, Tuple t)
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(is, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        std::apply([&ss](auto&... args){ ((ss >> args), ...);}, t);
        std::apply(func, t);
    }
}

template <typename Func>
void parse(std::istream& is, Func func)
{
    parse(is, func, typename function_trait<Func>::args{});
}
```

With usage:

```
auto forEach = [](int a, float b, string c){ cout << a << "," << b << "," << c << endl; }; 
parse(std::cin, forEach );
```

[Demo C++17](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a6dfcb9bfd06ce0)
[Demo C++14](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c89831a10426441)
For C++11, you have to implement `index_sequence` utility.

Some transformations are needed to handle functors with const reference such as `auto forEach = [](int, float, const string&) {/*..*/}`:

```
template <typename T> struct tuple_decay;
template <typename... Ts> struct tuple_decay<std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<std::decay_t<Ts>...>;
};
```

and so replace:

```
parse(is, func, typename function_trait<Func>::args{});
```

by

```
parse(is, func, typename tuple_decay<typename function_trait<Func>::args>::type{});
```

[Demo (C++17)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f3b8db6daf526e1)

Comment: While this looks to be approximately the correct idea, there seem to be a lot of typos (typename should be template in the first code chunk, etc). I cannot get this code to compile.

Comment: I will have to play around with it to see if I can get this working. It seems to require at least C++17.

Comment: @bremen_matt: Yes provided code uses C++17 (simpler and less verbose), but can be done in C++11/C++14.

Comment: I was hoping for a C++11 version so that it would work on some embedded hardware I have. But I am skeptical that you could get all of the function info you need in C++11.

Comment: That was quick. I will check it later.

Comment: @bremen_matt: link for C++17 and C++14. for C++11 you just need to implement `index_sequence`.

Comment: `parse` now uses `std::istream`, so you can handle `std::ifstream` from outside :-)

Comment: Yeah. That is simple.